# How to pass props to components in Routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using `withLayout` to wrap around each component in Switch Route. But by doing so, I cannot get `props` inherited in `SignIn` page. My App.js file is like below:

```
function withLayout(WrappedComponent, props) {
  // ...and returns another component...
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Layout>
          <WrappedComponent></WrappedComponent>
        </Layout>
      );
    }
  };
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
            <React.Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={withLayout(HomePage)} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={withLayout(SignIn)} />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={["/apply"]}
                  component={withLayout(NewQuote)}
                />
              </Switch>
            </React.Suspense>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

If I don't use the layout wrapper, I can simply do the following the get the props:

```
component={props => <SignIn {...props} />}
```

But now, how can I get props by using a wrapper around the component? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I can directly put following to make props passed do child component

```
<Route
                  exact
                  path="/login"
                  component={props => (
                    <Layout>
                      <SignIn {...props} />
                    </Layout>
                  )}
                />
```